# How to remove pop up on website (css changes not visible)?

Tags: themes, css, javascript

I'm working on this site and was asked to remove the pop up. I've tried entering classes like:

```
.popup, .popup .popup-bg {
    display: none !important;
}

.popup {
    display: none !important;
}
```

The js files were also obfuscated according to the original developer when I asked him about it. He also recommended the above and it does work in inspect but not when I make the changes in the file editor.

I also tried removing the below from the site.js file to see if that would make any changes and that didn't help.

```
133: function(t, e, n) {
            var i = n(106);
            t.exports = (i.default || i).template({
                compiler: [8, ">= 4.3.0"],
                main: function(t, e, n, i, a) {
                    return '<div class="popup">\n    <div class="popup-bg">\n\n    </div>\n\n    <div class="table">\n        <div class="popup-container table-cell middle">\n            <div class="video-overlay">\n                <div class="heading">\n                    <div class="table">\n                        <div class="table-cell middle">\n                            <div class="btn-close large">\n                                <svg version="1.1" id="Layer_1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" xmlns:xlink="http://www.w3.org/1999/xlink" x="0px" y="0px"\n                                   viewBox="0 0 73 73" style="enable-background:new 0 0 73 73;" xml:space="preserve">\n                                <style type="text/css">\n                                  .st0{fill:none;stroke:#cb1230;stroke-width:12.12;}\n                                </style>\n                                <path id="Shape_1_copy_2" class="st0" d="M68.7,4.3L4.3,68.7"/>\n                                <path id="Shape_1_copy_2_1_" class="st0" d="M68.7,68.7L4.3,4.3"/>\n                                </svg>\n                            </div>\n                        </div>\n                    </div>\n                </div>\n\n                <div class="embed">\n                    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/Ssqygh_c1Tg" frameborder="0" allow="accelerometer; autoplay; clipboard-write; encrypted-media; gyroscope; picture-in-picture" allowfullscreen></iframe>\n                </div>\n            </div>\n        </div>\n    </div>\n</div>'
                },
```

I also tried inline styling in the site file with no success.

I was thinking a work around potentially could be to create a new version (current is 0.2.8) of the assets to see if that fixes things but am unsure of how to go about this? **Does anyone have any idea as to why I'm having this issue with the pop up only?** I'm currently working off a staged site but [here is the live one](https://gracey.world/).

I've made changes in the css files for the newsletter and made other changes to the site with no issue.

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Since you have already made changes in various files, the code you are looking for can be found in the following file: `/assets/0.2.8/css/style.css`

Search around line 702 in FF devTools - may differ in other browser or in the original file:

```
.popup {
    letter-spacing: .1em;
    text-align: left;
    overflow: auto;
    z-index: 95
}
```

There, simply add `display: none;`. Alternatively, you can also add `.popup {display: none;}` to the very end of the mentioned file. Personally, I always try to avoid using `!important` first.

If no other rule is added for the popup at a later stage (e.g. through JavaScript), this should do the job. However, always **keep in mind** that **updating may overwrite** your modified files!

With that in mind, here is another solution. The prerequisite is the use of a child theme, otherwise you end up in the same update dilemma again. Place one of the following examples in your child theme's `functions.php` or if for any reason you no longer update your theme, in your theme's `function.php`. I've set the priority of the action hook to 99 for later execution, but you can use a different value (`default: 10`).

Use the CSS version to **hide** the element (again with or without `!important`):

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', function() {
   ?>
   <style>
       .popup {
           display: none !important;
       }
   </style>
   <?php
}, 99 );
```

Use the JavaScript/jQuery version to **remove** the element (be sure jQuery is loaded):

```
add_action( 'wp_footer', function() {
   ?>
   <script>
      jQuery( document ).ready( function( $ ) {
         $( '.popup' ).remove();
      } );
   </script>
   <?php
}, 99 );
```

It would be worth mentioning that, of course, all elements with the .popup class would always be affected - on all pages, posts and custom post types. So, if you want to limit this behavior to specific pages/posts, get the current page first before running the action hook.

As usual for WordPress, there are of course also various plugins with which you can place PHP, JS and CSS code in all possible places in WP, but that would go beyond the scope here.

Last but not least, you can also use the WordPress Customizer to add some custom CSS. In your case this would be `.popup {display: none;}` - with or without using `!important`.

Comment: Hi, thank you for your answer and I'm sorry for the delay! I am going to work on this tomorrow as I work on the weekends. I will be sure to accept your answer if it works.